# long mp3 from url loading too long on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, web, mp3

I'm new to this, so go easy on me if I happen to ask the obvious.

I'm fairly new to iPhone programming and now have the task to play an mp3 file from an URL. circumstances are:
 - the whole process is in phone gap and triggered from javascript, but I believe this is not causing the problem, please correct me if I'm wrong
 - the mp3s in question are usually longer than 1h

I've tried AVAudioPlayer, AVQueuePlayer, AVPlayer and Matt Gallagher's AudioStream. The first three options work great for a short mp3. For an 1 1/2h mp3 I need 2-4 min to load the file though. Matt Gallagher's AudioStream was faster, but still took 15sec to load and then started stuttering for about 20 sec before it continued normally.
My last option was to use AudioQueue, but I can't get it to work.

Which API would be advisable to use and what would be the necessary steps from starting with a NSURL or CFURLref. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this works fine for me so far:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

and then later I just use the normal `[audioPlayer play]` to start. There are more configurations possible, but the default does what I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is lower-level API for handling sounds.

Try OpenAL. Some tips [here](http://devnulldb.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-set-up-openal-and-play-sound.html) with [resources on GitHub](https://github.com/boringuser/devnulldb/tree/master/OpenAL-1). This [lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QQAzhwalPI) also can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the links. OpenAL does not seem to be working because it requires uncompressed audio. If I understand it right, I would have to download the file first and then convert it, so that would most likely cause loading time, right? The solution I found though, through your links is AVURLAsset --> AVPlayerItem --> AVPlayer. This one worked once, so I'll do more testing and then post the code.